# Java custom sorting characters

Tags: java, string, sorting

I have a string such as `crccoaaroac`.  How do I write use custom sort so that string has letters are in the following order:

```
1) c
2) r
3) o
4) a
```

Hence, the sorted string will be `cccrrooaaa`
I'm relatively new to Java.  I know how to sort ascending and descending but what is a good way to do custom sort this?

Comment: Break the string to an array of chars. Either do the sort manually with your custom orders, or use a Comparator. By the way: what happens if there is a fifth character (maybe 'x') in the string?

Comment: @NomadMaker I want to break it into a LinkedHashMap<Character,List<Integer>> but not sure how to custom sort it by key.  There's only those 4 characters.

Comment: I would just use a Set or maybe a HashMap<Character, Integer> (Character to hold the char, and Integer to hold the number of them). Your order is specific. You could either have an array ``char[] order = {'c', 'r', 'o', 'a'}`` or just hard-code it.

Comment: @NomadMaker could you write an example like: ```Map<Character, List<Integer>> mp = new LinkedHashMap<>(); mp.entrySet().stream().sorted( <WHAT DO I DO HERE??>) )```  I think it would be something like that in java 8?

Comment: I'd just use a loop. I retired without ever using the j8 streams.

Comment: @Nomad I think I'm supposed to use TreeMap then do something instead of LinkedHashMap.  I think I'm supposed to do an ```@Override custom comparator```. not sure how though.  I'd much rather NOT use an ```@Override``` implements method

Comment: If the only characters in your string are c, r, o, a, then you can just perform one loop to count the number of c, the number or r, the number of o and the number of a. Then perform a second loop to rewrite the string with the appropriate number of c first, followed by the appropriate number of r, etc. No need for LinkedHashMap or TreeMap; just 2 `for` loops and 4 integer variables to hold counters.

Comment: I want a single for loop as it would have a better time complexity.

Comment: Having one versus two loops does not necessarily have an impact on time complexity. Stef's solution would have O(n) complexity where n is the length of your input string.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stef said, you can do this by counting how often each character appears then re-writing them however often they appeared in the specific order you want.

```
import java.util.*;

public final class StackOverflow {

    private static String reorder(String s, char[] ordering) {
        Map<Character, Integer> charCount = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char currentChar = s.charAt(i);
            int currentCount = charCount.getOrDefault(currentChar, 0);
            charCount.put(currentChar, currentCount + 1);
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (char ch : ordering) {
            int count = charCount.getOrDefault(ch, 0);
            builder.append(String.valueOf(ch).repeat(count));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String reordered = reorder("crccoaaroac", new char[]{'c', 'r', 'o', 'a'});
        System.out.println(reordered);
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
ccccrrooaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you do that including comments:

```
        //your input
        String str= "crccoaaroac";
        // your character rank
        Map<Character, Integer> rank = new HashMap<>();
        rank.put('c', 1);rank.put('r', 2);rank.put('o', 3);rank.put('a', 4);
        // final result builder 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        //actual sorting using your custom comparator
        str.chars().boxed().map(e->(char)e.intValue() ).
        sorted((a,b)-> rank.get(a)- rank.get(b)).forEach(e-> sb.append(e));
        
        //final result
        String result = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) to define your custom sort order.

Per the spec (Enum#compareTo):

> Enum implements Comparable via the natural order of the enum (the order in which the values are declared).

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class CustomSort {
    enum CustomSortOrder {
        c,
        r,
        o,
        a,
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String unsorted = "cccaaaoorr";
        String sorted = unsorted.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
            .map(x -> CustomSortOrder.valueOf(String.valueOf(x)))
            .sorted()
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println(sorted);
    }
}
```

Edit: formatting

Answer (score 0):

An example of using a stream collecting to `LinkedHashMap` to maintain the order of insertion of the chars into the map (that is, for a string `ccooccroca` the result will be sorted as `cccccooora`):

```java
String s = "crccoaaroac";
        
String str = s.chars()
              .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                  x -> String.valueOf(x), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
              .entrySet()
              .stream()
              .peek(System.out::println)  // debug print
              .map(e -> e.getKey().repeat(e.getValue().intValue()))
              .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
         
System.out.println(str);
```

Output

```
c=4
r=2
o=2
a=3
ccccrrooaaa
```